# Laravel Events: updating vs updated?

Tags: php, events, laravel-5

What is the difference between `updating` and `updated` for [eloquent model events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events)?

My guess was that `updating` fires before a model is updated and `updated` after the model was updated. This implied to me that `updating` should always trigger when I update a model - even if no value has actually changed. However both events seem to only trigger when an event has actually changed a value in the DB. What is the difference then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not a model is to be updated is determined before actually calling update. The purpose of the updating event is to perform any tasks before writing to the database (and optionally abort the update). This makes sense because you don't want an event claiming that an update is about to happen to be fired when an update is not about to happen.

However the event that fires before an update or insert occurs always is the `saving` event which sounds like what you need. If you want a "pre-updating" event then listen on the `saving` event and check if `$model->exists` (otherwise the saving might be before an `inserting` event)

The relevant code is at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/edf4bb4e21107c124cd601616ef2b61aaf1c306e/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L544

```
 if ($this->fireModelEvent('saving') === false) {
         return false;
}
if ($this->exists) {
        $saved = $this->isDirty() ?
                    $this->performUpdate($query) : true;
} /* else insert */
```

And the calling of the `updating` and `updated` events happens in the `performUpdate`

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/edf4bb4e21107c124cd601616ef2b61aaf1c306e/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L609